# Using touchscreen cellphone lcd module for custom projects

Tags: lcd, stm32

I intend to use the capacitive touch based lcd modules of cellphones in custom embedded projects,
I will be using this display with low cost stm32 boards.

Has anybody experimented with this approach ? Any ideas, links to datasheets ?

PS : I am specifically looking for touch integrated lcd modules, there is a hack available for nokia non touch modules already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be easier, and much more cost-effective, to use LCD display + touchscreen integrated modules as sold on eBay or other sites, compared to using an LCD touchscreen from a cellphone.

For instance, this is a [2.2" TFT LCD with integrated touch panel](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-2-TFT-LCD-Module-Touch-Panel-176-x-220-Dots-262K-Colors-ILI9320-16bit-/180998595311?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a245b62ef), for **$6.79** (approximately Rs.370) including *free delivery to India*:
[image: TFT LCD + Touch Panel]

If integrating the fine-pitch FPC connectors of such LCD panels is a problem, you can also buy compatible [PCB adapters for such panels](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-8-2-4-inch-TFT-LCD-module-PCB-adapter-touch-IC-XPT2046-ads7843-for-arduino-/121019709027?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c2d563663) from eBay and other sites for as little as **$3.99** (~ Rs.216) including shipping, which incorporate required support components, providing a standard 0.1" pin-out that can be used with your embedded development board / breadboard.
[image: PCB adapter for LCD touchscreen]

I have been using such touchscreen display modules on projects, and can report that they work well, and that the existing library support for most such modules, on the common microcontroller development platforms, saves a lot of time, effort and implementation risk, far outweighing any perceived value of jerry-rigging any display panel off an existing cellphone.

Comment: Is this capacitive touch panel ? looks resistive to me.. I was under the impression the mobile phone ones costs much less. I will use these panels. Thanks.